# A comparison between the verbs "replace" and "substitute"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, verbs

I know that when you substitute X for Y it means that you replace Y with X. According to this rule, I need to make sure whether the following pairs mean the same or not. If not, then why?

> **1.a.** Yesterday l, I argued with the Boss and I think he's going to **replace me with Sam**. (The boss is going to fire me from the company and bring "Sam" as a permanent replacement for me.) 
>    **1.b.** Yesterday l, I argued with the Boss and I think he's going to **substitute Sam for me**.

And:

> **2.a.** While I'm away on vacation, another teacher will **substitute for me.** 
>   **2.b.** While I'm away on vacation, I will **be replaced with another teacher**